# Wrap or extend angular-material component allowing pass-through of unknown attributes to child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-decorator

We are using Angular 5 and material design and creating our own components with helper methods for various functions (i.e. dynamic column generation for `mat-table`).

I'd like a way to pass unknown attributes from my parent component onto my child component. This is easy in React, for example:

**App class render**

```
<MyDatatable knownVar="1" otherKnownVar="2" unknownButKnownToChildVar="3" />
```

**MyDataTable render**

```
<MatComponent {...this.props} />
```

This way if `MatComponent` ever updated what attributes it took in, `MyDataTable` wouldn't have to be updated. I've looked at the `@Input` decorator but this doesn't seem to facilitate unknown variables.

One solution I've thought of is to just pass in an object and account for that object via `@Input` but I don't like this because I would like the angular-material component documentation to accurately reflect how a developer should be using **my** `MyDataTable` component.

Short version of my question: *How do I pass unaccounted for attribute-level data to a child component in Angular 5?*

Comment: This doesn't exist in Angular, and it wouldn't work with AoT.

Comment: If you don't want to change the child component when the data changes, you surely must know what sort of data is being provided. Like a person component would receive a person as input. You can provide as many inputs as you want though. So you could define all your known inputs, and define one extra that does what you described in your solution.

Comment: Can't unknown variable be of Object type, so that in future it can contain attributes as much as required in form of Object's  properties?

Comment: Technically yes, and that's what I covered in the proposed solution section of my question. This however would not let you supply attributes on the component of any name. `<MyAngComponent unknownAttribute="1">` would be impossible to pass through to a child component without specifically supplying an `@Input` selector for `unknownAttribute` in `MyAngComponent` class

Comment: after a year, were you able to get around this?

Comment: Nothing decent unfortunately, the proposed answer was the closest I was able to figure out.

Comment: this probably the reason why angular and other frameworks don't have so many component libraries like react

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
              The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

        <!--  Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="column">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> column </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**Sample.html**

simply pass your datasource object which might come either from parent or from child component.

> dataSource = DATA ;

Hope u got my point or you require something different. As per your question dynamic data insertion to your table must bind to controller part .In term of angular if your datasource model get updated by child component as well as parent component.It render data as updation occur.

Show the code for your parent and child component data If possible?
Thanks

Comment: That was just a for example. The question is in regards to sending data through attributes that is unknown to the parent component but *is* known to the child component.

Comment: Currenctly there isn't any way of doing that in Angular. At least that i know of. There are workaround technics you could perform like hte above that i mentioned or using a service to feed your component with any data you want to. But Angular won't let you pass unkown attributes into the component.

Answer (score 0):

The one way i can think of doing what you want with the Input decorator that Angular provides is by passing a **JS Object (any)** into the Component Input and depending on the properties, execute the desirable code. Example:

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<my-component [data]="{data: 2, extraData: 3}"></my-component>
```

In that case you can add **n* number of properties** in the input data. There isn't any implementation for passing unknown number of attributes into the component.

An other cool thing you could also do is inside your component you could actually have some default values and also expect some more. Like the example here:

**app.component.html**

```
<my-component [data]="{name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'}"></my-component>
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = {
      name: "John",
      surname: "Doe",
      origin: "UK",
      ...this.data
    }
  }
}
```

**my-component.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="data.phone">
  Phone Number: {{ data.phone }}
</div>
```

Or even make some kind of **Object.keys(this.data)** and loop over the data properties and print the correct html. That way you can have some default values for the known properties and even expect some more unknown properties.

Hope I've been of any help.

Comment: This is a good implementation of the solution I proposed, however I guess the real answer to my question is what you (and other commenters) touched on when you said: "There isn't any implementation for passing unknown number of attributes into the component."